# C# WPF MVVM: Calling an Object

Tags: wpf, object, mvvm, properties, binding

I have a `QuestionsFile` class, which has questions, a name etc...

Now I have created a wpf application and I have a window which has different pages. These pages inherit the `BaseViewModel` class. I create my pages in the `WindowViewModel` class (where I pass a new `QuestionsFile` object to the constructor and dispatch it through the constructors of the other viewmodels):

```
var chooseQFVM = new ChooseQuestionsFileViewModel(this.QuestionsFile);
var showChosenQFVM = new ShowChosenQuestionsFileViewModel(this.QuestionsFile);

var pages2 = new List<WizardControlViewBaseModel>();
pages2.Add(chooseQFVM);
pages2.Add(showChosenQFVM);

pages = new ReadOnlyCollection<WizardControlViewBaseModel>(pages2);`
```

All these viewmodels inherit the `BaseViewModel` class which has the `QuestionsFile` property.

so when let's say I change the `QuestionsFile` property of the `chooseQFView` variable from a combobox and I give it through - the same property in the `BaseBiewModel` class must be changed. So this is this code of the property in the `BaseBiewModel` class:

```
public QuestionsFile QuestionsFile
    {
        get { return qfile; }
        set 
        { 
            qfile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuestionsFile");

        }
    }
```

So I call the `PropertyChanged` event, but when i want to call this property in the next page and I debug it says that all the properties of my `QuestionsFile` are null..

this is the code where I change the value of the `QuestionsFile` property:

```
public OptionViewModel<QuestionsFile> SelectedFile
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedFile;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedFile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFile");
            this.QuestionsFile = value.GetValue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you set some breakpoints to see what gets set and when?

Comment: First I create my windowviewmodel where I create a new Questionsfile, then I create my pages so the first block of code.. then I choose a questionsfile from the combo box and then I call the setter of the selectedfile, where I do this: this.QuestionsFile = value.GetValue(); and so the 'this' refers to the baseviewModel where he calls the setter for Questionsfile, then he does the propertychanged ofcourse

Comment: and the setter works, so when you debug it will set the questionsFile to the value... the only problem is when I try to call the getter of QuestionsFile..

Comment: So `qfile = value` works and it has the correct value, but when get is called, qfile has changed to null? Perhaps you have someone else modifying qfile, or you have a different ViewModel between set and get.

Comment: maybe for a little more info, this is what I do in the constructors of my viewmodels (which I create in the create pages(first block of code): public ChooseQuestionsFileViewModel(QuestionsFile qf):base(qf)
        { }

Comment: While I was editing your question I thought that you have created new property with the same name (`QuestionsFile`) in the derived class.

Comment: Did you set breakpoints and can state what happens (see my previous comment)?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand on your view you have a collection of  `QuestionFile`s (via OptionsViewModel) that you are selecting one of them via the `SelectedFile` property. At this point in time you are setting the chosen `QuestionFile` property.

This is all good for the `ChooseQuestionViewModel` (which I assume contains the `SelectedFile` property). I am not sure this is your issue but the `SelectedFile` will not reflect inside the `ShowQuestionsFileViewModel` because now both view models refer to a different instance.

Is this your issue? That you cannot see change of the selected `QuestionFile` in the `ShowQuestionsFileViewModel`?

If so you will need to tell the other view model that it has changed via events or having it reference the `ChooseQuestionViewModel` so it can listen for the `PropertyChanged` event so you can grab the selected item from and update itself.

i.e.

```
//Ctor
public ShowQuestionsFileViewModel(ChooseQuestionViewModel chooseViewModel)
{
    _chooseViewModel = chooseViewModel;
    chooseViewModel.PropertyChanged += ChoosePropertyChanged
}

private void ChoosePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Property == "SelectedFile")
    {
        this.SelectedFile = _chooseViewModel.SelecteFile;
    }
}
```